# What is statistical difference?

Tags: noise, differential-privacy

In the paper "[Calibrating Noise to Sensitivity in Private Data Analysis](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F11681878_14.pdf)" by Dwork et al., the term "statistical difference" is used as following (in page 280):

> Finally, if a $1 − \gamma$ fraction of the $z$’s are $\delta$-good for a particular pair $(r, b)$, then the statistical difference between the distribution $p'(z)$ and $p(z)$ is at most $2(\gamma + \delta)$.

where $\delta$-good is defined as:

> A value $z$ is $\delta$-good for a pair $(r, b)$ if $p'(z) − p(z) \leq \delta · p(z)$.

What is the term "statistical difference" as used in this paper? It seems it is not defined anywhere else in the paper and it is used as if something well-known.

Comment: it's not well known

Comment: According to one of the [top Google hits on "privacy 'statistical difference',"](http://www.people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/diffprivcourse/spring13/definition-notes.pdf), the "statistical difference" might be the [Total Variation Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures).